# When should you use form.clientsize and when form.size()?

Tags: .net, forms, powershell, winforms

I'm trying to make a simple GUI in Powershell to display a table using the DataGridView but I'm not sure if I should use `form.ClientSize` or `System.Drawing.Size()` to define the client size.

I've seen both but couldn't find any explanation why/when you should use one or the other.

Example:

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1280, 720);
```

*vs.*

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;
$form.ClientSize = '1280, 720';
```

Comment: `Form.Size` includes non-client area, other one doesn't.

Comment: Set the `Form.Size` if you're mean to set the size of the whole Window, `Form.ClientSize` if you mean to set a specific size to the client area. The `Size` will change accordingly -- The WinForms Designer in Visual Studio serializes the `ClientSize` Property value when you set the `Size` Property of the Form in the PropertyGrid, calculating the difference

Comment: You typically use `ClientSize` at design time, to make sure the form will be big enough to fit all of your controls. `Size` is usually used only at run time (and then calculated, not hard-coded), e. g. when restoring Windows size from a settings file. As others wrote, it depends on the current system theme, how large the window frame and caption will be and thus the difference between `Size` and `ClientSize` can vary on different machines.

Comment: @zett42 This is nonsense. The dynamics between `Size` and `ClientSize` have nothing to do with "design time" vs "run time". It is very likely that one might need to query or change the `ClientSize` at run time to account for non-client elements such as scroll bars, borders, title bars, and menus. It is also very plausible that one might not need to micro-manage the `ClientSize` at design time in case of proper use of anchoring, docking, and auto-sizing.